# How to truncate string before POST?

Tags: php, post, truncate

I'm currently trying to teach myself PHP, so forgive my lack of understanding.

I am trying to post two strings to my database. The first string (div1) can be long, and the second string (title) should be a truncated version of the first, such as 15 characters, used as a title.

Through searching the internet, I've found a function to help me, but I'm struggling to implement it. I have tried to cobble together two functions, but I don't know how. The post does work. It can send the div1, but when trying to add the truncate function, it stops working.

This is the post action file (saveNewText.php). The include 'header.php' has a require for the functions.php file.

```
<?php include 'header.php' ?>

<?php

    // remove these 3 lines, and it'll work again
    $original_string = $newText;
    $max_chars = 15;
    $newTitle = truncate_string_at_word($original_string, $max_chars);

    // this part works when the above 3 lines are not included, except it's not posting a title yet
    $newText = $_POST['newText'];
    if ($newText != ""){
        $sql = "UPDATE notetable SET div1 = '".$newText."', title = '".$newTitle."' WHERE id=1 "; // how to truncate the title?
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    }

?>
```

This is the function from the functions file (functions.php).

```
<?php

function truncate_string_at_word($string, $max_chars)
{
  $string = trim($string);
  if (strlen($string) > $max_chars) {
    $string = substr($string, 0, $max_chars);
    $pos = strrpos($string, " ");
    if ($pos === false) {
      return $string;
    }
    return substr($string, 0, $pos);
  } else {
    return $string;
  }
} 

?>
```

Comment: [Teach yourself prepared statements](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli#prepare) while you're learning

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: You're trying to reference `$newText` before it's defined. Your `$newText = $_POST['newText']` line should be **before** `$original_string = $newText`

Comment: There's no need for the `$original_string` variable. Just use `$newText` when you call `truncate_string_at_word()`. But as @Phil says, those 3 lines need to be after you assign `$newText`.

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unparameterised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values. If you learnt your current technique from a tutorial or book, please don't use that resource again.

Comment: @Phil: Thank you for the link. I'll check it out. 

I've tried to put it before, but it won't let me post at all. 

@Barmar:
No errors at all. I'm checking phpmyadmin/sql database to see if it works.
I've also tried to to call the `$newText` in the `truncate_string_at_word` variable, but it stops posting when I put the `$newText = $_POST['newText'];` above the code.

@ADyson: Thank you. I haven't gotten to the security, but I'm aware of the issue yet, and watched a few tutorials on PHP security. Everything will be rewritten when I better understand how :)